# Cloudinary openUploadWidget throw error in my react app

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary

I seem not to be doing something right, but I don't know what. I need to open cloudinary upload widget in my web app and it keeps throwing this error; TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6_cloudinary___default.a.openUploadWidget is not a function.

I am using react and this is how I am using it...

```
    load = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    cloudinary.openUploadWidget({ cloud_name: 'classvideo', upload_preset: 'classVideo' },
      function (error, result) { console.log(result) });
  }
```

This is how I tried rendering it on the click of a button inside my render method...

```
   <div>
      <button onClick={this.load}>upload Image</button>
   </div>
```

and this is the script tag in my html

```
  <script src="//widget.cloudinary.com/global/all.js" type="text/javascript" />
  <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Is there something I'm doing the wrong way? what does webpack have to do with this?
please help

Comment: `cloudinary` will be a global object if you are using the script tag. Maybe you are also writing something like `import cloudinary from 'cloudinary'`? Try removing that line if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks, @Tholle now I see I need no import statement.
Removing the import statement and adding 'window.' to the back of 'cloudinary.openUploadWidget' works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `window.cloudinary.openUploadWidget({..`

Answer (score 2):

`cloudinary` will be a global object if you are loading it with a separate script tag.

If you remove your import that shadows the global object it will work as expected.

```
// import cloudinary from 'cloudinary';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are landing on this post but are using Angular instead, note that you have to:

- include the script in angular.json
  [image: angular.json]
- reference the script from index.html
  [image]
- ...and then declare the cloudinary variable in the component
  [image]

Notice that I am not using the remote script reference but have downloaded the widget source code and have included it in my project.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [React Cloudinary Uploader](https://github.com/app-masters/react-cloudinary-uploader) for Rect, it's a good solution at this time to handle Cloudinary in React.